# Using linq to store id in object, but display name in gridview?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

If I've got a linq statement like this in my ASP.NET website:

```
var abcList =
            (from c in backEnd.GetCList()
             join a in backEnd.GetAList()
                 on c.AId equals d.AId
             join b in backEnd.GetBList()
                 on c.BId equals e.BId 
             orderby c.CId descending
             select new ABC
             {
                 AId = a.AId,
                 BId = b.BId,
                 CId = c.CId,
             }).ToList();
```

For the objects a and b, there is also a.AName and b.BName. I want to save the attribute ID in the object ABC, but I want the a.AName to be displayed instead of a.AId. Is that possible to solve?

So I want the object A to consist of the AId alone, but in a GridView I want to display the AName where c.AId = a.AId. Hope it's not too confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, just add a place for `AName` in `ABC`, and show it instead in your GridView.

```
public class ABC
{
    public int AId { get; set; }
    public string AName { get; set; }
    // other stuff
}

 // in your query
 select new ABC
 {
     AId = a.AId,
     AName = a.AName,
     BId = b.BId,
     CId = c.CId,
 }
```

You could make this code a bit cleaner (IMO) if you move the property assignments to a constructor:

```
select new ABC(a, b, c)
```